# Bind Button.CommandParameter to MVVM object to use the same ICommand to different Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have quite a hard time to figure out the solution to a rather trivial problem of mine.

I have three buttons that execute the same command (same function call). The only thing that changes is that the function call affects different objects per button. So instead of creating the button command 3 times I just created Command parameters that I bind to different MVVM objects. My code below will clear things up.

My problem is that I don't know how to bind a command parameter to an MVVM object. Towards this direction I get back the following error

```cs
Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding cannot be converted to 'System.Boolean' //or System.String
```

XAML code to bind the elements together *(I have added also the `MultiBinding.Converter` method as proposed in the submitted answer by Peter)*

**XAML file**

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestEnvironment.MainWIndowTestStackOverflow"
        x:Name="MainWindowTestStackOverflow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestEnvironment"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="720"
        Width="1145"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5"
        WindowStyle="None">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="GridMain"
         Width="1145"
         Background="White"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         ShowGridLines="False" 
         Grid.Row="1">
        <!--Grid Columns-->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="195"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="295"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="650"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Grid Rows-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="52"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox
            Name="FileNameTextBox"
            Text="{Binding Path=FilesFilePath}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="5,0,0,0"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            FontStyle="Italic"
            FontFamily="Arial"
            FontSize="9"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Grid.Row="1"/>
        <!--Apply ICommand to browse file 1st time-->
        <Button 
            x:Name="BrowseButton1"
            Content="Browse"
            Command="{Binding Path=BrowseButtonCommand}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableFilesBrowseButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Width="80" 
            Height="25"
            Margin="40,0,0,0"
            Padding="0"
            FontWeight="Light"
            FontSize="10"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Cursor="Hand">
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <local:BrowseButtonConverter/>
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <Binding Path="FilesFilePath"/>
                    <Binding Path="EnableFilesBrowseButton"/>
                    <Binding Path="EnableFilesLoadButton"/>
                    <Binding Path="EnableFilesViewButton"/>
                    <Binding Path="FilesPanelVisibility"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
        <Button 
            x:Name="LoadButton1"
            Content="Load"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableFilesLoadButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Focusable="False"
            Width="80"
            Height="25"
            Margin="135,0,0,0"
            FontSize="10"
            FontWeight="Light"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Cursor="Hand">
        </Button>
        <StackPanel
            x:Name="StackPanelFiles"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Width="400"
            Height="36"
            Margin="235,0,0,0"
            Visibility="{Binding XPath=FilesPanelVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        </StackPanel>
        <Button
            x:Name="PreviewButton1"
            IsEnabled="{Binding XPath=EnableFilesViewButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Focusable="False"
            Content="View"
            Width="80"
            Height="25"
            Margin="545,0,0,0"
            FontSize="10"
            FontWeight="Light"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Cursor="Hand">
        </Button>
        <!--Apply ICommand to browse file 2nd time-->
        <TextBox
            Name="FileNameTextBoxLayout"
            Text="{Binding Path=LayoutFilePath}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Height="25"
            Margin="5,6,0,0"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            FontStyle="Italic"
            FontFamily="Arial"
            FontSize="9"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Grid.Column="2" 
            Grid.Row="3"/>
        <Button 
            x:Name="BrowseButton2"
            Content="Browse"
            Command="{Binding Path=BrowseButtonCommand}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableLayoutBrowseButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Width="80" 
            Height="25"
            Margin="40,0,0,0"
            Padding="0"
            FontWeight="Light"
            FontSize="10"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Cursor="Hand">
            <Button.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <local:BrowseButtonConverter/>
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <Binding Path="LayoutFilePath"/>
                    <Binding Path="EnableLayoutBrowseButton"/>
                    <Binding Path="EnableLayoutLoadButton"/>
                    <Binding Path="EnableLayoutViewButton"/>
                    <Binding Path="LayoutPanelVisibility"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.CommandParameter>
        </Button>
        <Button 
            x:Name="LoadButton2"
            Content="Load"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableLayoutLoadButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Focusable="False"
            Width="80"
            Height="25"
            Margin="135,0,0,0"
            FontSize="10"
            FontWeight="Light"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Cursor="Hand">
        </Button>
        <!--...The rest of the controls as created above but with different names-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The binding elements like `FilesFilePath`, `EnableFilesBrowseButton`, etc are MVVM objects that bind to other XAML objects and get affected by the ICommand.

Now I present to you the c# code with the MVVM objects and ICommand function:
**.cs file**

```cs
namespace TestEnvironment
{
    //Command parameters
    public class BrowseButtonCommandParameters
    {
        public string FilePathSelected { get; set; } //parameter 1
        public bool EnableBrowseButton { get; set; } //parameter 2
        public bool EnableLoadButton { get; set; } //parameter 3
        public bool EnableViewButton { get; set; } //parameter 4
        public bool VisibilityPanel { get; set; } //parameter 5
    }
    //Browse - MultiValueConverter
    class BrowseButtonConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Error handling omitted for brevity
            // Casting omitted because question's code has insufficient context
            return new BrowseButtonCommandParameters
            {
                FilePathSelected = (string)values[0],
                EnableBrowseButton = (bool)values[1],
                EnableLoadButton = (bool)values[2],
                EnableViewButton = (bool)values[3],
                VisibilityPanel = (bool)values[4],
            };
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("to-source binding mode not supported");
        }
    }
    
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //MVVM objects binded to xaml objects and connected to ICommand parameters

        //Used by BrowseButton1
        //1.
        private bool _enableFilesLoadButton;
        public bool EnableFilesLoadButton
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableFilesLoadButton;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableFilesLoadButton = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableFilesLoadButton");
            }
        }

        //2.
        private bool _enableFilesBrowseButton;
        public bool EnableFilesBrowseButton
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableFilesBrowseButton;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableFilesBrowseButton = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableFilesBrowseButton");
            }
        }

        //3.
        private bool _enableFilesViewButton;
        public bool EnableFilesViewButton
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableFilesViewButton;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableFilesViewButton = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableFilesViewButton");
            }
        }

        //4.
        private string _FilesFilePath;
        public string FilesFilePath
        {
            get
            {
                return _FilesFilePath;
            }
            set
            {
                _FilesFilePath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FilesFilePath");
            }
        }

        //5.
        private bool _changeFilesPanelVisibility;
        public bool FilesPanelVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                return _changeFilesPanelVisibility;
            }
            set
            {
                _changeFilesPanelVisibility= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FilesPanelVisibility");
            }
        }

        //Used by BrowseButton2
        //1.
        private bool _enableLayoutLoadButton;
        public bool EnableLayoutLoadButton
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableLayoutLoadButton;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableLayoutLoadButton = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableLayoutLoadButton");
            }
        }

        //2.
        private bool _enableLayoutBrowseButton;
        public bool EnableLayoutBrowseButton
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableLayoutBrowseButton;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableLayoutBrowseButton = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableLayoutBrowseButton");
            }
        }

        //3.
        private bool _enableLayoutViewButton;
        public bool EnableLayoutViewButton
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableLayoutViewButton;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableLayoutViewButton = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableLayoutViewButton");
            }
        }

        //4.
        private string _LayoutFilePath;
        public string LayoutFilePath
        {
            get
            {
                return _LayoutFilePath;
            }
            set
            {
                _LayoutFilePath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LayoutFilePath");
            }
        }

        //5.
        private bool _changeLayoutPanelVisibility;
        public bool LayoutPanelVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                return _changeLayoutPanelVisibility;
            }
            set
            {
                _changeLayoutPanelVisibility= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LayoutPanelVisibility");
            }
        }


        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //ICommand: BrowseButtonCommand
        public ICommand BrowseButtonCommand
        {
            get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(FuncBrowseCommand); }
        }
        public void FuncBrowseCommand(object parameters)
        {
            var param = (BrowseButtonCommandParameters)parameters;

            //Load button gets instantly disabled when every time the user clicks the Browse Button 
            param.EnableLoadButton = false;

            Nullable<bool> browse_result = BrowseFile(param.FilePathSelected);

            //Browse file
            if (browse_result == true)
            {
                param.EnableBrowseButton = true;
                param.EnableLoadButton = true;
                param.EnableViewButton = false;
                param.VisibilityPanel = false;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: Inside the ICommand function `BrowseButtonCommand` I call a method named `BrowseFile`. Don't pay attention to that because the function I present works perfectly.*

My goal and concern is how can I bind the command parameters with the MVVM objects and adopt their values. How to pass a command.parameter value to an MVVM object. For example, I want the Command Parameter `FilePathSelected` to get the value of the MVVM object `FilesFilePath`

And then when I use the same command for a different browse button `BrowseButton2` I should be able to provide the values of the MVVM objects of my second Browse Button like

```cs
<Button 
    x:Name="BrowseButton2"
    Content="Browse"
    Command="{Binding Path=BrowseButtonCommand}">
    <Button.CommandParameter> //Parameters that share value with MVVM objects of the second Browse Button
        <local:BrowseButtonCommandParameters FilePathSelected="{Binding Path=LayoutFilePath}" //those return the error I mentioned earlier.
                                             EnableBrowseButton="{Binding Path=EnableLayoutBrowseButton}"
                                             EnableLoadButton="{Binding Path=EnableLayoutLoadButton}"
                                             EnableViewButton="{Binding Path=EnableLayoutViewButton}"
                                             VisibilityPanel="{Binding Path=LayoutPanelVisibility}"/>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Do you know how can I achieve this? I think I am on the correct path, although it's clear that I miss something. I have created my MVVM objects, my ICommand function, although I want to bind them together so the one to take the value of the other. As I mentioned I need to do this for three Browse Buttons (`BrowseButton1`, `BrowseButton2`, `BrowseButton3`). Thus, I don't want to create three ICommands but rather only one.

I am more than willing to share with you more info about my question in case there is something misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide [a minimal, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it's impossible to know for sure. But based on the error message, I would expect that the `BrowseButtonCommandParameters` is not a dependency object, and thus cannot be the target for any binding.

Most likely, what you need to do is use an `IMultiValueConverter` to copy the source values into an instance of `BrowseButtonCommandParameters` for your command. For example:

```cs
class BrowseButtonConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Error handling omitted for brevity
        // Casting omitted because question's code has insufficient context
        return new BrowseButtonCommandParameters
        {
            FilePathSelected = values[0],
            EnableBrowseButton = values[1],
            EnableLoadButton = values[2],
            EnableViewButton = values[3],
            VisibilityPanel = values[4],
        };
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack (object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("to-source binding mode not supported");
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML, you can do something like this:

```xml
<Button  x:Name="BrowseButton1"
         Content="Browse"
         Command="{Binding Path=BrowseButtonCommand}">
  <Button.CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding>
      <MultiBinding.Converter>
        <local:BrowseButtonConverter/>
      </MultiBinding.Converter>
      <Binding Path="FilesFilePath"/>
      <Binding Path="EnableFilesBrowseButton"/>
      <Binding Path="EnableFilesLoadButton"/>
      <Binding Path="EnableFilesViewButton"/>
      <Binding Path="FilesPanelVisibility"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Comment: Peter thanks for your answer. I will test it and let you know about the result. As you have correctly understood (based on your answer). I have 5 MVVM objects for BrowseButton1, and 5 another MVVM objects (same purpose but different name) for BrowseButton2. Both Browse Buttons have the exact same functionality. So instead of making 2 ICommands, I want to pass the MVVM objects as Command.Parameters and change the UI..

Comment: Peter a comment regarding your answer. When I plugged it in my code it returns a type error about the ```value``` parameter. Since I use booleans and strings I can't set those to objects. Based on your answer ```values``` is set to type ```object```. However, in my code ```FilePathSelected``` is a string. After I used ```FilePathSelected=(string)values[0]``` my xaml UI disappeared

Comment: _"in my code `FilePathSelected` is a string"_ -- then you will need to cast. Which you say you tried, but note that the converter may be called in situations where the data context hasn't been set yet. You need to add code the converter to check the values, and only return the initialized `BrowseButtonCommandParameters` object when you can do so successfully. Consider disabling the command (i.e. have `CanExecute()` return `false`) when the converter returns an invalid object (you can use `null`, `DependencyObject.UnsetValue`, for example). As I noted in my answer, you didn't provide ...

Comment: ... a [mcve], so it's impossible to post code in the answer that is guaranteed to work. You'll need to take the general approach in the answer and spend the time to understand it, so that you can then apply that general approach to your specific scenario.

Comment: Peter I have edited my question based on your asnwer and some additional code about Null checks I found here https://sodocumentation.net/wpf/topic/3950/value-and-multivalue-converters. So basically, your solution works. Altough, I get an error of null reference when I use the same command parameter for a different ICommand. This is out of the scope of the question so I will create a new one. For example, in my question I have the Browse command. Now imagine that I have also the Load command (for Load button). Both ICommands share the ```FilesFilePath```.

Comment: To continue my comment above. ```FilesFilePath``` get its value from the Browse Command and its not null. But when I pass it as a command parameter for the Load Button it returns null. Somehow ```FilesFilePath``` loses its value when I pass it as a parameter in Load Command (```<Button  x:Name="LoadButton1" Command="{Binding Path=BrowseButtonCommand}">{Binding Path=BrowseButtonCommand}"> <MultiBinding.Converter> <local:LocalButtonConverter/></MultiBinding.Converter><Binding Path="FilesFilePath"/>```